# Forms acting unexpectedly

Tags: vb.net

I'll try to explain this best I can.

I have windows form application that contaions numerous forms. The first form 
to open is a non modal form that acts as command form to issue various formats to
the underlying reservation program. A second form also opens which is basically my
Main form for the application. This form contains multiple check boxes to run methods
that make changes to the reservation program. This form is also modeless. Each box that
is checked runs concurrently and performs methods to delete, change and add to the 
res program below. Various boxes may be checked at any given time. Below is code to 
handle the checkboxes:

```
Private Sub frmOWTMain_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.Hide()  'here i want to hide the OWTMain form
        Call ckforPNR()
        If Me.cbPricing.Checked Then
            Call doPricing()
            Me.cbPricing.Checked = false
        End If
        If Me.cbUdids.Checked Then
            frmUdids.Show()
            Me.cbUdids.Checked = False
        End If
        If Me.cbMod.Checked Then
            Call doModUdids()
        End If
        If Me.cbFare.Checked Then
            Call doFareSavings()
            Me.cbFare.Checked = False
        End If
    End If
    Me.show()  'This is the problem. This runs during method calls. All I'm
       'looking to do is re display the OWTMain form.   
End Sub
```

At this point I would want to re display the OWTMain form above. This is
where I am having an issue. As you can see, a number of methods are called
which involve showing other forms to the user. I do NOT want any of these 
forms to be modal because I want the original first opened form to still be
able to issue commands to the res program toview information needed by the other forms.

Here is an example of some of the method calls:

```
Private Sub doPricing()
    Dim myPrice As New Pricing   'a call to another class that handles pricing
    If myPrice.getTQT = False Then
        frmAddPricing.ShowDialog()  'showing new forms
    Else
        frmCurPricing.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub doFareSavings()
    Dim myPrice As New Pricing
    If myPrice.checkForFS = False Then
        frmFS.ShowDialog()  'showing new forms
    End If
    If myPrice.checkForFS = True Then
        frmFSVerify.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I call any of these methods the form OWTMain shows prematurely while other
forms from the called method are still running. I expected the code at the top to run
in order of the calls but that is not the case. I just want to re display the OWTMain
form after all the code is run.  I have not been able to figure this out without
creating a ton of code to minipulate the opening and closing of the windows.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
John

Comment: It seems to me that you should remove most of that code from that event handler.  Show the first form modelessly, i.e. by calling `Show`, and handle its `FormClosed` event.  In that event handler, decide what to do next.  Do that for each of the other forms.  After the last one has raised its `FormClosed` event, show the original form again.

Comment: if you look at that first block: `if chkbox checked // do something // uncheck it` - that is how a button works.  As is, it doesnt quite fit with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

This will check if all sub forms are closed and then re-show the main form.

remove the exitsing me.show()

```
Public Sub ReShowMainForm()
    ' add all sub forms to this check
    if frmFS.Visible = false andalso 
       frmUdids.Visible = false andalso
       frmFSVerify.Visble = false then 
      Me.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

change xyzForm.Show to xyzForm.Show(me) to make the main form available as parent to the sub forms.

Handle the FormClosed event in each sub form and add the following code

```
DirectCast( me.parent, frmOWTMain).ReShowMainForm()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean in this line: "change xyzForm.Show to xyzForm(me) to make the main form available as parent to the sub forms. Is xyzForm the main form or does it apply to all the other forms I need to show? There will be about 10 separate methods running in order of boxes checked with each method having multiple forms. Thank you, I really do appreciate your time. John

Comment: sorry. I missed the crucial detail. I ment to say add the parameter (Me) to all ShowDialog calls. example: frmAddPricing.ShowDialog(Me)

Comment: schudel, Thank you very much. This is the direction I took, but instead of checking each form's visibility separately, I looped through all the open forms (except the starting form) and checked the visible property of each. Then I opened the main form. Again, thanks. Your code got me to a solution afte a week of trying. Many thanks.